# C code for finding 1(factorial)2(fac)+2(fac)3(fac)+...9(fac)10(fac)

Tags: c

I am new to programming and have just started with array. This was my code for the problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i=1,f=1,num,fac[10],sum=0;
    for (num=1; num<=10; num++) {
        for (i; i<=num; i++) {
            f = f * i;
        }
        fac[num-1]=f;
    }

    for(i;i<=9;i++)
        sum = sum + fac[i] * fac[i+1];

    printf("The sum is %d",sum );
    return 0;
}
```

Output it is giving is-The sum is 0

So what are the corrections to be made or any other code for the problem?

Comment: where is code ?

Comment: `fac[i+1]` is out of bounds when `i == 9`

Answer (score 1):

You need to reinitialize the variable `i` more often.
Instead of having a for loop that looks like `for (i; i<=N; i++)`, initialize `i` and do `for (i=0; i<=N; i++)`